# Big sur "unable to check for updates"

Tags: software-update, big-sur

For some reason, I cannot update my MacBook Pro (13', 2017) running Big Sur (11.1). Every time I try using the Software Update tool I get that it is "Unable to check for updates". If I try updating from the App Store (whose icon indicates that there is 1 pending update), a blank window shows up.

[image: unable to check for updates]

As an alternative, I have tried running on the terminal and it identifies there is an update pending

```
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: macOS Big Sur 11.2.2-20D80
    Title: macOS Big Sur 11.2.2, Version: 11.2.2, Size: 3173800K, Recommended: YES, Action: restart,
```

However, running with flags `-i -a` results in no action. Rebooting does not do the job. I have also tried resetting the NVRAM, to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5826458?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing those files. Thanks